# Can you programmatically accept a spelling correction in UITextView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, autocorrect

I have a button that inserts a character into a UITextView.  I want this button to behave as the spacebar button does; I want the pending autocorrect suggestion to be accepted upon pressing it.

Can this be done?  If so, how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any API to interact directly with autocorrect. However, there is a bit of a hack I ran across not long ago: if you resign the responder, the currently displayed autocorrect will be accepted. So, you may be able to get away with resigning the first responder and then assigning it again:

```
[myTextView resignFirstResponder];
[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Does the UI muck up when you do this?

Comment: No. I've not had any problems with it.

Comment: Awesome, I may use this in the future.

Comment: FYI:  this triggers the textViewDidEndEditing: and textViewShouldBeginEditing: delegate calls and the keyboard notifications.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out that instead of doing this (kills my animations) you can use:

```
  [messageField reloadInputViews];
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: @mahboudz I believe the case of the question is that... why downvote??

Comment: The original poster says nothing about `inputView` nor `inputAccessoryView`.  Are you assuming that the poster's "button" is one of these?  It doesn't have to be, and that makes your definitive solution incomplete.  You may wish to reflect this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the two proposed solutions work on iOS 14 without any side-effects like weird animations on older devices.

Calling selectionWillChange and selectionDidChange however works:

```
[textView.inputDelegate selectionWillChange: textView];
[textView.inputDelegate selectionDidChange: textView];
```

A similar and more popular question can be found here: [Execute current UITextField autocorrect suggestion when another button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4611525/2310837)