# Execute current UITextField autocorrect suggestion when another button is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am implementing chat in my application, very similar to the iPhone's built-in Messages app. I have a UITextField next to a button. The user types something into the text field, and very often the text field suggests various autocorrections. In the built-in Messages app, tapping the Send button will cause the currently visible autocorrection suggestion to execute. I am seeking this behavior in my application, but haven't been able to find anything.

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically execute the currently visible autocorrection/autocomplete suggestion of a UITextField when a completely separate control is activated? It's obviously possible somehow.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Call `-resignFirstResponder` on the field. That forces it to accept the autocorrect. If you don't want to dismiss the keyboard, you can immediately follow that with a call to `-becomeFirstResponder` again.

Comment: If you're going to call `-becomeFirstResponder` again, make sure that it actually had focus to begin with. Use the `editing` property to test this (checking `isFirstResponder` doesn't work on UITextFields).

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Your additional comment was also quite helpful!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without resigning first responder, which has the effect of triggering both keyboardWillHide and keyboardDidHide?

Comment: @esilver: Not that I am aware of. I have not tried to find a solution to this problem in many years though, so it's possible there's a separate way.

Comment: @esilver: added an answer that covers your case. This one plagued me for months, too.

Comment: I move the `UITextView` elsewhere with animation on tapping a button. While I get the updated text by calling `resignFirstResponder` earlier, the floating suggestion animates to the old position which looks weird. If I give it after the animation or within the animation block, it disappears instantly, and of course has the additional chicken and egg problem of needing updated text to compute final position to then call `resignFirstResponder` to get updated text :P This can be solved with an approximation but avoiding that would be much cleaner.

Comment: This does not work on iPhones SE and 6S with iOS 14. The keyboard will animate or not accept the autocorrection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892341/2310837 still works though.

Answer (score 11):

For esilver: you can do this without resigning first responder by having a different textfield becomeFirstResponder and then having the relevant textfield becomeFirstResponder. The keyboard will not move in this case, and not trigger any hide notifications. If you don't have any other textfields, create a dummy textfield and set it to hidden = YES.

```
-(void)tappedSendButton:(id)sender
{
    // This hack is in place to force auto-corrections to be applied
    // before the text is sent.
    [self.dummyTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.toolbar.textView becomeFirstResponder];

    [self sendChatWithBody: [self.toolbar.textView.text copy]];
}
```

Comment: I had a BOOL to ignore the delegate keyboard will appear messages, but still left issues with an index in a table view re-updating with a visible animation. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone trying the dummy text field strategy, make sure it has the same parent superview or else becomefirstResponder will be ignored!

Comment: And don't forget to set the properties `inputAccessoryView`, `inputView` and `keyboardType` in the same values as a original `UITextView` to avoid unwanted keyboard events.

Answer (score 9):

Since resigning and re-assuming first responder may have side effects (lots of notifications, keyboard show/hide triggers, etc), I've been looking for an alternative, less brutal way. After quite some search, I found this is all you need to do to accept autocorrections in a `UITextView` (or `UITextField` fwiw):

```
[textView.inputDelegate selectionWillChange: textView];
[textView.inputDelegate selectionDidChange: textView];
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Worked for me. iOS 9.2.1. Thanks Max.

Comment: this method is less intrusive, and it fixes some unwanted animations in a table view, which happen instead using the resign/become first responder method

Answer (score 4):

This code was solve problem in my case.

```
[self.textView rejectAutoCorrect];
```

Category code.

```
@implementation UITextView (rejectAutoCorrect)

- (void)rejectAutoCorrect
{
    if ([self isFirstResponder])
    {
        [self.inputDelegate selectionWillChange:self];
        [self.inputDelegate selectionDidChange:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Since you only call methods of `inputDelegate`, this code works by accident. I'd do this `self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length);`

Answer (score 0):

Building on Nick Locking's suggestions, here is a category method we wrote to process any pending autocorrect suggestions without dismissing the keyboard (and without triggering the will/did hide/show notifications).

```
@implementation UITextView (SuggestionHelpers)

- (void)acceptSuggestionWithoutDismissingKeyboard {
    // by making another UITextField the first responder, the keyboard won't try to hide
    UITextField *temp = [[[self class] alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    temp.hidden = YES;
    [[self superview] addSubview:temp];
    [temp becomeFirstResponder];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [temp removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick clean recap of solutions discussed...

Create a dummy textview to make responder and then return to original textview. make sure it was first responder.

**setup:**

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];

self.dummyTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[self.dummyTextView setHidden:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.dummyTextView];
```

**Method:**

```
- (void)commitSuggestions {
    if([self.textView isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.dummyTextView becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```